# Logic App/JavaScript - Remove Matching Values

Tags: javascript, azure-logic-apps

I have two data sources. Data Source 1 is basically a list of Projects and Users assigned to those Projects. Data Source 2 is a list of Users that I want to remove from the Projects in Data Source 1.

Data Source 1:

```
[
   {
      "db1Project":[
         {
            "projectCode":"1",
            "assignment":{
               "db1User":[
                  {
                     "assignee":"wantzc"
                  },
                  {
                     "assignee":"michelles"
                  }
               ]
            }
         },
         {
            "projectCode":"2",
            "assignment":{
               "db1User":[
                  {
                     "assignee":"stallinga"
                  },
                  {
                     "assignee":"domanl"
                  },
                  {
                     "assignee":"brantleyd"
                  }
               ]
            }
         },
         {
            "projectCode":"3",
            "assignment":{
               "db1User":[
                  {
                     "assignee":"cinnamonk"
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

I want to match "assignee" from Data Source 1 with "sponsor" in Data Source 2.

Data Source 2:

```
[
   {
      "db2Users":[
         {
            "sponsor":"wantzc"
         },
         {
            "sponsor":"patem"
         },
         {
            "sponsor":"stallinga"
         },
         {
            "sponsor":"oliviaa"
         },
         {
            "sponsor":"brantleyd"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Then remove non-matching "assignee" and generate below output:

Desired Output:

```
[
   {
      "db1Project":[
         {
            "projectCode":"1",
            "assignment":{
               "db1User":[
                  {
                     "assignee":"wantzc"
                  }
               ]
            }
         },
         {
            "projectCode":"2",
            "assignment":{
               "db1User":[
                  {
                     "assignee":"stallinga"
                  },
                  {
                     "assignee":"brantleyd"
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Can this be done using Logic App only? If not, how to do this using JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

This is a little bit of a verbose way to do it in Javascript, but the idea is relatively simple:

1. Create a map of the users you're looking for so you have an O(1) lookup instead of O(n) lookup each time
2. Filter the users list for each project to only contain users found in the db2Users list
3. Add the project to the new results set if any db1Users remain after step 2

This will take 1 pass through your original array, so it's an efficient, yet simple algorithm to do what you're trying to do.

```js
let data = [{"projectCode":"1","assignment":{"db1User":[{"assignee":"wantzc"},{"assignee":"michelles"}]}},{"projectCode":"2","assignment":{"db1User":[{"assignee":"stallinga"},{"assignee":"domanl"},{"assignee":"brantleyd"}]}},{"projectCode":"3","assignment":{"db1User":[{"assignee":"cinnamonk"}]}}];

let db2Users = [{"sponsor":"wantzc"}, {"sponsor":"patem"}, {"sponsor":"stallinga"}, {"sponsor":"oliviaa"}, {"sponsor":"brantleyd"}];

let db2UsersMap = db2Users.reduce((res, curr) => {
  res[curr.sponsor] = true;
  return res;
}, {});

let filteredProjects = data.reduce((res, project) => {
  let currProjUsers = project.assignment.db1User;
  project.assignment.db1User = currProjUsers.filter((user) => db2UsersMap[user.assignee]);
  if (project.assignment.db1User.length > 0) { res.push(project); }
  return res;
}, []);


console.log(filteredProjects);
```